# Do ArcGIS Online feature services support a DISTINCT or returnOnlyUniqueValues option?

Tags: query, arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

ArcGIS Server REST API has:

```
returnDistinctValues    
Description: If true, then returns distinct values based on the fields specified in outFields. This parameter applies only if the supportsAdvancedQueries property of the layer is true.
Values: <true | false>
Example: returnDistinctValues=true
```

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000r1000000

Is there an equivalent when querying agol feature service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS Online / ArcGIS.com is a platform/portal which contains a whole bunch of functionality, but it also exposes its feature services via the ArcGIS Server REST API.

Log into your ArcGIS Online account then go to My Content and click on the feature service. Under the *Layers* section, click on the hyperlink - this will take you to the REST endpoint for this service.

However, it unfortunately appears that while ArcGIS Online does support the ArcGIS Server REST API, it **doesn't** support the returnDistinctValues option.

(The REST API's [query](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000r1000000) page mentions "This parameter applies only if the supportsAdvancedQueries property of the layer is true" which is possibly the reason this doesn't work.)

Comment: Yes understood, but i didn't see the returnDistinctValues parameter.  This parameter is the focus of the question

Comment: @bcollins what happens if you append returnDistinctValues to the REST endpoint's query statement, eg `http://<featurelayer-url>/query?where=1%3D1&f=html&returnDistinctValues=true` ?

Comment: yeah i've tested.  The returnDistinctValues parameter doesn't exists http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Query_Feature_Service/02r3000000w5000000/

Comment: That's disappointing - I'll update this answer. Sorry I couldn't help!